# Returning the ROW_NUMBER() with PARTITION

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server, windows-forms-designer

I am using C# and SQL.

I would like to add auto insert value depends upon the number of times column"name" data inserted on the day.Each day each person might have multiple data insert.
Everyday data insert per name might be vary.
Example. person maria has 3 insert on that day therefore "Column2" shows 1 ,2 ,3.

Expected output.
[image]

Here key identifier is name .

C# and SQL method does. appreciate your support.

button click code.

```
protected void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
    con.ConnectionString = ("Data Source=APC;Initial Catalog=d;Integrated Security=True");
    con.Open();
    GETDATE())"; 
    String st = "INSERT INTO t4 (twenty,ten,five,one,five_hundred_fils,five_hundred_fils2,sar,hundred_fils,fifty_fils,twenty_five_fils,ten_fils, five_fils,time,total,name) values (@twenty, @ten, @five, @one, @five_hundred_fils,@five_hundred_fils2,@sar, @hundred_fils,@fifty_fils, @twenty_five_fils, @ten_fils,@five_fils, GETDATE(),@total,@name)";
      SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(st, con);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@twenty", label18.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ten", label6.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@five", label5.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@one", label4.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@five_hundred_fils", label10.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@five_hundred_fils2", label25.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@hundred_fils", label19.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fifty_fils", label20.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@twenty_five_fils", label21.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ten_fils", label22.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@five_fils", label23.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@total", label8.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", textBox13.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sar", label27.Text);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();

}
```

```html
My sql for display
SELECT id, twenty, ten, five, one, five_hundred_fils, hundred_fils, fifty_fils, twenty_five_fils, ten_fils, five_fils, time, total, name FROM dbo.t4
```

Comment: While I'm not a big fan of database triggers because they aren't very discoverable, and trigger on insert for that table might be a good way to accomplish that. That's something you would create in SQL Server and the data would be generated when you insert a record.

Comment: Can't see any VB.net code.

Comment: Do you need column2 editable? If not, then you could use just query to count entries inside same day.

Comment: Column2 is either way. Can you advise revised query as per your suggestions

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest going about it differently. Add a date column and populate it with the date of the insert. Any time you want to know a count by day use a query to GROUP BY [name] and [date] and do a count(). That way later on you could get a count by week, month or even hour, if you'd like.

```
SELECT COUNT(Column1) AS CountPerDay, Name, CAST(time as Date)
FROM     t4
GROUP BY Name, CAST(time as Date)
```

Comment: Hello troy thanks. date time date type is there already in database.  query already there just i need add additional details to derive my results. can you advise..

Comment: troy i tried ,SELECT COUNT(name) AS CountPerDay, Name, time
  FROM [d].[dbo].[t4]
GROUP BY Name, time. but result in CountPerday is shows all value 1.

Comment: I assume your "time" field is DateTime. If you cast it to Date it should group properly. I updated the answer.

Comment: I realized I missed something. I just updated the answer again.

Comment: Troy thank you but. i expect like this 1.Maria,Date 2. Maria,Date,3.Maria,Date but as per your code its shows Countperday is 3 Name maria and date

Answer (score 1):

```html
SELECT * FROM ( SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY name ORDER BY name DESC) AS StRank, * FROM [d].[dbo].[t4]) n
```

[image]I tried in different way and got the results.